# Qt OpenCL headers

Tags: qt, opencl

I really tried hard searching, still appear to miss the obvious.
I get that one needs no specific OpenCL library nowadays, as it should be provided with whatever graphics card and driver is installed. But where do I get the headers, using Qt 5.7? There appear to be no `<CL/cl.h>` or any `cl.h` headers whatsoever. 
Or did I get it all wrong, and still need to install some AMD or NVidia SDks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways: You can either install one of the vendor SDKs, which will contain the OpenCL header(s), or you can get them directly from Khronos here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/

What version you use is up to you; personally I use the version that matches the minimum hardware we support, which prevents me from using any API that is too new. You can also use newer headers and a #define to set the version. Your choice.

BTW, this is independent of Qt. Qt did have an OpenCL wrapper, but it is no longer supported and out of date so I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, that did help. I was looking out for QtOpenCL too, but it looks like not useable as you pointed out. Would be great if they got that sorted and OpenCL becomes more generic in general, at least for projects that don't require the absolute maximum performance for a particular platform.